# How can I make allow users with older versions of iOS to download an older version of my app

Tags: ios, app-store

I've updated my app and due to some of the functions I'm releasing it has to be for iOS 10 and up. I understand that there is a way for users that have not upgraded to iOS 10 to be able to get the older version of my app but I haven't been able to figure out how to enable that in the app store. I just tested on a device and currently if you have iOS 9 it will tell you that you can't get the app because it is only supported on iOS 10. No option to download the previous version.

According to the redit article below Apple enabled the behavior I want. I just don't know how to turn it on for my app.

https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/1mjw36/people_with_old_ios_devices_you_can_now_install/

So to update everyone:  This only works if the app is already purchase.  All new purchases will force to upgrade to the latest OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this feature just works if you already purchased the app and want to reinstall it.

A solution would be to purchase the app on your Mac and then try again on the iOS device.

Here is an article about it: https://sites.google.com/site/appleclubfhs/support/advice-and-articles/app-store-downloading-older-versions-of-apps-ios